# decide whether or not expressions are norms, in the space of continuously differentiable functions.

Tags: general-topology

consider the space of continuously differentiable functions over $[a,b]$
decide whether or not expressions are norms.

1. $ máx~_ {t \in [a,b]}  | x' \ (t)|$

Solución:
no, of course because if x (t) = 1 (for example) its norm would be null, but it is not the null function.

2. $ \ ( máx ~ _{t \in [a,b]}~ | x' (t) |) + | x (a)| $

Solución:
yes it is since : $ \| x (t) \| \ge 0 $

$ \| x (t) \|= 0$ if and only if $x (t)$ is the constant null function.
$ \| \lambda * x(t) \| = | \lambda | \| x(t) \| $

$ \|x(t)+ y (t) \| \le \| x(t) \| + \| y (t) \|$
It is enough to note that the maximum of the sum is less than or equal to the sum of maximums.

b) The norms $\| ~ \|_1 and \| \|_2 $ are said equivalent, if and only if, there are real numbers, $α> 0, β> 0$  such that $ α \| \|_1≤\| \|_2≤β\| \|_1$.

Consider the relation $\| \|_1∼\| \|_2$  if and only if, $\| \|_1$ and $ \| \|_2 $ are equivalent, check that $ ∼$ is an equivalence relation.

Solución:

if it is a norm, by the reflexive properties (every norm is equivalent to itself); symmetric (if 1 is equivalent to 2, 2 is equivalent to 1); transitive (if 1 is equivalent to 2 and 2 is equivalent to 3, then 1 is equivalent to 3).

for the symmetric:

$ \alpha , \beta > 0 $

$α\| \|_1≤\| \|_2 $ then $ \| \|_1≤ \frac{1}{\alpha}~ \| \|_2 $

$\| \|_2≤β\| \|_1 $ then $ \frac{1}{\beta} \| \|_2≤\| \|_1$

then:

Then:

$αα' \| \|_1≤\| \|_3≤ββ′\| \|_1$

c) consider $(X, \| \|) $ Banach space, prove that $ (X × X, \| \|_0)$ where $ \| (x, y) \|_0 = max (\|x\|, \|y\|)$ is a Banach space.

this right ? part c) how is it demonstrated? I appreciate your help please

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are correct. For c) you need to prove that $\|.\|_0$ defines a norm and that the space is complete. The norm property is easy to show (everything trivial except triangular inequality. For that one again argue that the max of a sum is smaller then the sum of the maxima.

For the completeness: If $(x_n,y_n)$ is a Cauchy-Sequence, show that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$. As $X$ is Banach we get limits $x,y$. Then argue that $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$.

Comment: Please can you help me with this part C)? I am practicing for an exam. and I need to study these demos a lot. thanks for your help.

Comment: @angelabayona What do you need help with in c?

Comment: yes, with part c) please.

Comment: For part c) I’ve given you the general steps to take, please elaborate on which part you struggle with. You need to prove the two properties of a banach space, that is normed and complete. Can you do $\|\cdot\|_0$ is a norm?

Comment: if $ \ {(x_n, y_n)} $ is Cauchy then for all $ϵ> 0$ there exists $ N∈N$ such that for all $m, n $ greater than N is $ ∥ (x_m − x_n, y_m − y_n) ∥0 = max {∥x_m− x_n∥, ∥ $ as much  $ m − y_n∥} <ϵ$ . Since both $∥y_m − y_n∥ $ and $∥y_m − y_n∥ $ are less than $ max {∥x_m − x_n∥, ∥y_m − y_n∥} < $ϵ both are Cauchy sequences. , please Lazy, if it is not correct, help me

Comment: Yes, that is correct (basically you’re using that the norms of the projections are bounded by $\|.\|_0$). Now use that $X,\|.\|$ is Banach, so you get limits $x,y$. Then show that $(x,y)$ is the limit of $(x_n,y_n)$ (so prove that if both $\|x-x_n\|\to0$ and $\|y-y_n\|\to 0$ then also $\|(x,y)-(x_n,y_n)\|_0 \to 0$).

Comment: Lacy, I hope I don't bother you, but now those other parts that you tell me I don't know how to do, please help me

Comment: You have already shown that if $(x_n,y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence irt $\|\cdot\|_0$ then $(x_n),(y_n)$ are CS wrt $\|\cdot\|$. But we know $X$ is complete wrt $\|\cdot\|$, so then $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge against some $x,y$. So the only thing we still need to demonstrate is that $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$. For this consider: If for some $\epsilon$ we have $\|x-x_n\|<\epsilon,\|y-y_n\|<\epsilon$ then also $\|(x,y)-(x_n,y_n)\|_0 = \|(x-x_n,y-y_n\|_0 = \max(\|x-x_n\|,\|y-y_n\|) < \epsilon$. Thus since for each $\epsilon$ there is some $N=\max(N_{(x_n)},N_{(y_n)})$ so that for all $n\geq N$ we

Comment: have $\|x-x_n\|<\epsilon$, $\|y-y_n\|<\epsilon$. Thus $\|(x,y)-(x_n,y_n)\|_0<\epsilon$. But thus $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$ und thus $X^2$ is complete wrt $\|\cdot\|_0$.